# Brackets in maths

Tags: probability

I’ve not done math in so many years I’ve see an equation that I do not understand... could someone please explain it in ways that I could write an application for it.

```
    (19)(5) - (13)(5) + (7)(5)
      4  0      4  1     4  2

   3876 x 1 - 715 x 5 + 35 x 10 = 651
```

$${19 \choose 4}{5 \choose 0}-{13 \choose 4}{5 \choose 1}+{7 \choose 4}{5 \choose 2}$$

In my application the numbers within the brackets will change and I know where these come from... I suppose my question is what is meant by 19 over 4 and 5 over 0 and how does that equate to 3876 x 1?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense as written.  Can you post the original equation, and explanation somehow?

Comment: I formatted the equation (and brackets!) properly using MathJax. Please take a look how I did that so you know how to do that for next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the ['choose' function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). In general, $m \choose n$ is the number of ways you can choose a (unordered) group of $n$ elements out of a group of $m$ (distinct) elements.

Comment: It should be `out of a group of $m$ (distinct) elements`

Comment: @AlainRemillard oops, thanks! :)